# can i braodcast a UDP package to part of a network?

Tags: c++, networking, udp

i am trying to broadcast a UDP package using subnet.
i want to braodcast my package to 192.168.1.255 ?
can i do that ? and how using c++ ?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337422/how-to-udp-broadcast-with-c-in-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using C++, I'd recommend using the [Boost ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) package for networking. The only gotcha is to be sure to set the broadcast ability on your UDP socket via:

```
boost::asio::socket_base::broadcast option(true);
socket.set_option(option);
```

The "Examples" section of the boost documentation should have plenty of references to get you up and running.